# Unable to get error logs from VS remote debug/deploy

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to deploy and debug my project on remote machine. My attempt to deploy and debug my code fails and Visual Studio provides me with following log:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: ProjectName, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas how I may get more output with some actual error codes?

Environment:

MSVS 2019 16.11.5

Verbosity level -- diagnostic both for build output and log file

Comment: Can you ping your remote machine and is it running the remote debugger at the right version with the proper parameters?

Comment: Yes I can, even see that my files are deployed where I want sometimes. But in the end it always fails with logs as shown in post. I'm not trying to troubleshoot deployment itself right now. I'm just trying to make this fabulous IDE to actually give me error log instead of exiting with "Something Went Wrong" output.